# Multiple choices of gauge for a single many-body wavefunction in non-relativistic quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, schroedinger-equation, gauge-invariance, many-body

It is known that in a single particle quantum mechanics problem with the Hamiltonian, $H = \frac{(\vec p-q\vec A)^2}{2m} + V(\vec r)$, one can perform the following gauge transformation:

$$\vec A \rightarrow \vec A' = \vec A + \vec \nabla \lambda(\vec r),$$

provided we also transform the wave-function, $\Psi(\vec r) \rightarrow \Psi'(\vec r) = e^{iq\lambda(\vec r)/\hbar} \Psi(\vec r) $, so that the Schr$\ddot o$dinger equation remains satisfied.

However, if we have multiple particles with the Hamiltonian being,

$$H = \sum \frac{(\vec p_n-q\vec A_n)^2}{2m} + V(\vec r_n),$$

is one allowed to choose the gauge for each term $\vec A_n$ differently for each particle?

Also, would the corresponding wave-function after gauge transformation look like $$\Psi'(\vec r_1, ..., \vec r_N) = e^{\frac{iq}{\hbar}\sum \lambda_n(\vec r_n) } \Psi(\vec r_1, ..., \vec r_N)~?$$

I tried to verify if this is true and it seems to be so. In that case, this is very strange since a single source of magnetic field will give rise to as many gauge choices as there are particles.

Comment: Your conclusion is (almost) correct following your premises, but let me check if you intended to ask the question you did. By putting an $n$ label on $\vec{A}_n$, you are saying that you have as many different gauge fields as you have particles. In other words, each particle is coupling to a different field. This means that you aren't really talking about *the* electromagnetic field, which is the same for all charged particles. If you want to talk about the electromagnetic field, you should just have $\vec{A}$, and you have to simultaneously transform all particles with the same $\lambda(x)$.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. There is a single electromagnetic field and I am exploring the possibility whether I can choose different vector potentials $\vec A_n$ (all equivalent under gauge transformation) for different particles.

Comment: In other words, let's say I choose some gauge and get the expression for $\vec A$. Now 1) if I alter the gauge is the total wave-function transformed by a factor of $~e^{i\lambda}$ or $~e^{iN\lambda}$ where $N$ is the number of particles. 2) Looking at the form of the Hamiltonian can I treat each $\vec A$ term that couples to a $p_n$ term differently? Can I choose the gauge for each of the $\vec A_n$ term differently?

Comment: Ah ok. In that case the answer is no. You start with one $\vec{A}$ field, and if you do a gauge transformation, then $\vec{A}$ has to transform in the same way in each place it appears in the Hamiltonian. What you are saying amounts to having $N$ different gauge potentials, which is logically fine, but not the situation you are interested in. I'll turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In electromagnetism there is one vector potential, $\vec{A}$. So the correct way to write the Hamiltonian is

\begin{equation}
H = \sum_n \frac{(p_n-q_n \vec{A})^2}{2m_n} + V(\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2,...\vec{r}_N)
\end{equation}

This Hamiltonian is invariant under gauge transformations of the form (apologies if I get a sign wrong)
\begin{eqnarray}
\Psi_n &\rightarrow& e^{i q_n \lambda(\vec{r}_n)/\hbar} \Psi_n \\
\vec{A} &\rightarrow& \vec{A} + \nabla \lambda
\end{eqnarray}

ie, the vector potential transforms the same way each place it appears, and *all* fields transform with the same $\lambda(\vec{r}_n)$, with the exact phase factor determined by the charge $q_n$. It is not consistent to allow the same field ($\vec{A}$) to transform in different ways if it appears in multiple places in the Hamiltonian.

(Note: in an earlier version I wrote $x$ instead of $\vec{r}_n$ as the argument to $\lambda$, but changed this due to a comment)

**Aside**

Based on the comments, what follows from this point is *not* the situation the OP is interested in. But, for completeness, I'll note we *can* consider a situation with $N$ vector potentials (where $N$ is the number of particles). We can represent this situation with a Hamiltonian

\begin{equation}
H = \sum_n \frac{(p_n-q_n \vec{A}_n)^2}{2m_n} + V(\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2,...\vec{r}_N)
\end{equation}

which would be invariant under $N$ different gauge symmetries (the group is then $U(1)^N$). In this situation, we can transform each field separately. Let me use $j$ to label the fields, to try to make it obvious there is a difference with the situation above, in that here only two fields are transforming, $\Psi_j$ and $\vec{A}_j$, as opposed to $N+1$ in the case of electromagnetism.
\begin{eqnarray}
\Psi_j &\rightarrow& e^{i q_j \lambda_j(\vec{r}_j)/\hbar} \Psi_j \\
\vec{A}_j &\rightarrow& \vec{A}_j + \nabla \lambda_j
\end{eqnarray}
In this situation, since there are $N$ different vector potentials, it is consistent for them each to transform in a different way.

Comment: In the single vector potential case, when you write $e^{iq_n\lambda(x)/\hbar}$ as the transformation factor, what does $x$ refer to? The wavefunction is a function of the 3N coordinates $\vec r_1, ... \vec r_N$.

Comment: I'm assuming we have $N$ distinguishable particles, so then I can write the state of each charged particle $\Psi_n$. Then $x$ is short hand for $\vec{r}_n$.

Comment: Oh okay! And I guess the total factor for the indistinguishable case would be the product of all such exponential factors of one variable. Thanks.

Comment: Right, you could form a Slater determinant to build the state for distinguishable fermions, for example, but I think it amounts to what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

You have a single electromagnetic field described by single
potentials $\vec{A}(\vec{r},t)$ and $V(\vec{r},t)$.
These potentials extend over the whole space (all $\vec{r}$).

And you have $N$ particles
represented by the wave function $\Psi(\vec{r}_1,\dots,\vec{r}_N,t)$.

Then the Hamiltonian is
$$H=\sum_{n=1}^N\left
(\frac{1}{2m}(\vec{p}_n-q\vec{A}(\vec{r}_n,t))^2
+qV(\vec{r}_n,t)\right).$$
Notice that you still have only one electromagnetic field ($\vec{A}$ and $V$).
However, only the field values at positions $\vec{r}_n$ are relevant,
because the electromagnetic interaction takes place only where the
particles are.

Then Schrödinger's equation is
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\left
(\frac{1}{2m}(\vec{\nabla}_n-q\vec{A}(\vec{r}_n,t))^2
+qV(\vec{r}_n,t)\right)\Psi(\vec{r}_1,\dots,\vec{r}_N,t)
=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(\vec{r}_1,\dots,\vec{r}_N,t)$$
where $\vec{\nabla}_n$ is with respect to $\vec{r}_n$.

It is easy to verify that this Schrödinger equation is invariant
to the following gauge transformation:
$$\begin{align}
\vec{A}'(\vec{r},t)&=\vec{A}(\vec{r},t)+\vec{\nabla}\lambda(\vec{r},t) \\
V'(\vec{r},t)&=V(\vec{r},t)-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\lambda(\vec{r},t) \\
\Psi'(\vec{r}_1,\dots,\vec{r}_N,t)&=
  e^{iq\lambda(\vec{r}_1,t)/\hbar}...e^{iq\lambda(\vec{r}_N,t)/\hbar}
  \Psi(\vec{r}_1,\dots,\vec{r}_N,t)
\end{align}$$
Notice that you have one common function $\lambda$.
Otherwise gauge invariance would not hold.